# Revolution of a solid with no clear boundaries

Tags: calculus

My book never explains how to do a problem like this.

I have

$y = 16-2x$

$y=6$

$x=0$

about x-axis

I know that the graph has an upper bound of 6 and lower of 0. So I do

$$\int 36 - (16-2x)^2 dx$$

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you draw the picture, you'll find that your region is a triangle. Its *bottom* edge is on the line $y=6.$ Its *top* edge is on the line $y=16-2x.$ [Don't forget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_method#Washer_method) you'll also need to find the horizontal bounds of the integral, and multiply the whole thing by $\pi$. What you're looking for, then, is something of the form $$\pi\int_a^b(16-2x)^2-36\,dx,$$ where $a,b$ should be apparent from the picture of the region.

Comment: @PaulthePirate: then you haven't drawn the picture.

Comment: @PaulthePirate: The idea here is that we're starting with a region having an outer curve (the one furthest from the $x$-axis) and an inner curve (the one closest to the $x$-axis). We are **then** trying to find the volume of the solid of revolution of that region about the $x$-axis using the washer method.

Comment: @PaulthePirate: Take a look at the graph [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=region+bounded+by+x%3D0%2C+y%3D6%2C+and+y%3D16-2x). Does that triangle match the picture you've drawn?

Comment: @CameronBuie Yeah, I just thought x=0 was y =0.

Comment: @Paul: Easy mistake to make. Is it clearer to you now what is going on? Have you heard of the washer method for finding the volume of a solid of revolution?

Comment: @CameronBuie Yes, that is next on my list to study. I just can't forumlate these into the proper set up I really struggle with that no matter how meticulously I draw the graph.

Comment: Don't I have to substract 6 to make up for the hole in the center?

Comment: No, we do not want to subtract $6$. The upshot is that we deal with the outer curve first, treating it like the radius of a "differentially thin" cylinder, having (in this case) "differential volume" $\pi(16-2x)^2\,dx.$ The volume of the solid within the surface made by rotating the outer curve (which in this case looks like a truncated cone), then, is $$\int_a^b\pi(16-2x)^2\,dx=\pi\int_a^b(16-2x)^2\,dx.$$ (Have you figured out what $a,b$ are, yet?) But we aren't done, yet. We're interested only in the stuff *between* the outer and inner curves, so we have to toss some of that stuff out. ...

Comment: ... In particular, we aren't interested in the stuff within the inner curve. Treating the inner curve in the same sort of way, we find that the volume of the solid within the surface made by rotating the inner curve (in this case, just a cylinder) is $$\pi\int_a^b6^2\,dx.$$ The volume we're interested in, then, is $$\pi\int_a^b(16-2x)^2\,dx-\pi\int_a^b6^2\,dx=\pi\int_a^b(16-2x)^2-6^2\,dx.$$

Comment: @Paul: If we were to subtract $6$ from both, we'd be finding the volume of the solid given by shifting that triangle so that the bottom edge lay on the $x$-axis, and *then* rotating about the $x$-axis. These are two different solids, and do not have the same volume (as you can check).

Comment: @Paul: One more note...shifting the triangle down to the $x$-axis *will* give you another triangle with the same *area* (which is probably what you were thinking). However, rotating these triangles about the $x$-axis gives us two different *volumes*. Let me give you a nice heuristic to help visualize why this should be. Consider: (1) a doughnut with a two inch hole in the middle that is two inches thick all the way around; (2) a doughnut with a hole in the middle a mile wide that is two inches thick all the way around. The latter needs more dough, despite having the same cross-sectional area.